Proving a system is linear time invariant
Given the following system
y’ + ty = x(t)
My notes gave the following steps and concluded the system is time variant instead.

I do not get the statement saying the following “y0(t) and y(t - t0) are solutions to DIFFERENT differential equations.” What does it mean by different differential equations?

I agree that this is strange wording. What I think they're trying to explain is that the differential equation for \$y_0(t)\$ (the response to delayed input \$x(t−t_0)\$) has coefficients based on \$t\$, while the equation for \$y(t−t_0)\$ (the delayed output) has coefficients based on \$t−t_0\$​. Therefore, these are structurally different equations, as the coefficients of \$y(t)\$ and \$y(t−t_0)\$ differ. This difference demonstrates that the system is indeed time-variant.
